# Fancybox jQuery conflicts with other jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, conflict, operator-precedence

I only discovered that it was the Fancybox code after much testing...

After referencing all the necessary FB files I'm calling an external .js file with:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'type': 'image',
    'titlePosition': 'outside',
    'width': 640,
    'height': 640
});

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
helpers: {
    overlay: {
        css: {
            'background': 'rgba(41, 44, 51, 0.8)'
        }
    }
 }
});
```

Either of these statements causes other jQuery to stop functioning. They seem innocuous enough so I'm wondering if this is a precedence issue? Should I be calling Fancybox code before/after other code?

Judging by (many) other posts here on SO, there seems to be a theme with Fancybox jQuery conflicts...

Comment: Are you sure this is the way to initialize fancybox? You seem to initialize it twice here

Comment: I had seen these suggested everywhere, but never together, so I left them separate. I tried combining them into one initialization but it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Have you check your console, any errors?

Comment: BOINK! I had been dynamically including the Fancybox.js only as needed...without realizing the other .js file was always initializing ".fancybox". Solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. When a site is already working correctly and you need add a new jquery plugin, you should add it in the end of jquery list.
2. Done that, verify the Jquery version (check both FB to js), if it is too newer may not be supported yet. Use any older.
3. Use any alternative plugin jquery to resolve your issue.

Hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is: check which elements/files are actually loaded before assuming it's a conflict...javascript console, stupid! (thanks, roasted)

Comment: Uh, this was me posting the answer to my own question...why the down vote? :(